# SVN Commit Failed... Can't Move... Transaction '836-nr' cleanup failed...Can't Remove directory

Tags: windows-7, svn, tortoise-svn

We have an SVN repository we access using Tortoise.
The host machine is a Windows 7 PC.

Today I went to make a commit of a file change and got the following error:

```
**Commit failed (details follow):
Can't move
 '\\gary-pc\Users\Public\ST365_R1_SVN\db\transactions\836-nr.txn\svn-5955FEDD'
 to '\\gary-pc\Users\Public\ST365_R1_SVN\db\transactions\836-nr.txn\props': The
 process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
Additional errors:
Transaction '836-nr' cleanup failed
Can't remove directory
 '\\gary-pc\Users\Public\ST365_R1_SVN\db\transactions\836-nr.txn': The
 directory is not empty.**
```

I have rebooted the hosting computer. No joy.
The SW developer who installed this is no longer with the company so I am the SVN administrator. GULP.

There are no other users on the computer at present.

I have found no good way to google this problem and so I have come here.

Is there some sort of clean up I need to do from a CMD window on the host?

If it is a permission problem how do I check?

Not sure when the host computer may have taken Windows update(s).

Answer (score 0):

Update. 
**Summary:** The problem went away.

A friend and I did some blue sky ideas for what to try:

Turn off anti virus and try again.

Tortoise has a command line utility. Might help.

Close all file browser windows..

Turn off file previews.

Look at log for user permissions that might have become elevated by
another user commit.

Try pulling copy of PCB onto another machine.

Try getting the back up onto fresh hardware / computer.

Yesterday I checked to make sure that there were no other Windows explorer instances open that might have been the process capturing the file. There were none.
I rebooted the machine again.
I checked to turn off anti virus and found it had been turned off by my predecessor (ugh.) 
I learned that a coworker was able to successfully pull down a fresh checkout of the project in question the afternoon before. I again tried the same commit that had not worked the morning of the day before and it worked. 
Everything seams to be normal now. 
I turned on anti virus.

Another entry for the journal of irreproducable results.